# How can I apply 4th order Runge-Kutta to a Laplacian equation in spherical coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, spherical-coordinates, poissons-equation, runge-kutta-methods

Can someone please help me solve the Poisson-Boltzmann equation in spherical coordinates over the domain $r\in(r_0, \infty)$ with Runge-Kutta:

$$
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}\right) =a \sinh \left(\frac{\psi}{\psi_0}\right)
$$

here $r$ is the radial coordinate, $a$ and $\psi_0$ are constants. The boundary conditions are $\psi=\psi_0$ and $\psi'=b$ at $r=r_0$.

I made an attempt to put the equation into a form suitable for Runge-Kutta integration with a $u$-substitution $u/r=\psi$, yielding

$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}=a r\sinh\left(\frac{u}{r\psi_0}\right)
$$
And, following from this the Runge-Kutta method can be applied
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\begin{bmatrix} 
u  \\
\partial u/\partial r \\
\end{bmatrix}=f\left(u, \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}, r\right)=\begin{bmatrix} 
\partial u/\partial r \\
ar\sinh\left(\frac{u}{r\psi_0}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This seems to work, but my question is: Is there a more direct way of applying Runge-Kutta without such a substitution?

Comment: In order to use numerical methods, we need some boundary conditions.

Comment: thx i added them

Comment: just in case you didn't know there is also [Scientific Computing SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) where Mathematics-based answers [are also posted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29149/17869)

Comment: If you have ODEs, rather than PDEs, why use $\partial$?

Comment: Youre right about $\partial$ not necessary just force of habit from my Engineering classes.

Comment: You could define $u=r^2ψ'$, then $u'=ar^2\sinh(ψ/ψ_0)$, $ψ'=u/r^2$. Is this more direct for you? Transformations are good if they keep the resulting state variables in a bounded range, this makes variable-stepsize methods easier to apply.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I wanted. Make this an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it please